# Get the inserted values from inside a ItemAdding event

Tags: list, event-handlers, events, list-item

Is it possible to get the values that were inserted (to create an item in a list) from inside the [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) event?

For `ItemAdded` the data is available in `properties.ListItem`, but for `ItemAdding` this is `null`.

Is there some way to retrieve the data inserted by the user in the create form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `properties.AfterProperties`, should hold the data for ItemAdding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.afterproperties.aspx